# NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat align bottom right

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout

I want to put a indicator view in a bottom right of container view, i have this code to insert view

```
var img:UIImageView?
            img         = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: singleCheckViewWidth, height: singleCheckViewHeight))
            img!.image  = UIImage(named: "check")
            img!.tag    = 21
            img!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            img!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            //Aggiungo la vista al fumetto
            cell.textView!.addSubview(omg!)
```

The problem is that with this code i have icon in a top left with 10px margin and it works fine:

```
let iconVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:|-10-[indicator(\(singleCheckViewHeight))]",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += iconVerticalConstraints

            let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:|-10-[indicator(\(singleCheckViewWidth))]",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += horizontalConstraints
```

here is image:

[image]

but if i try to move image in a bottom left with this code:

```
            let iconVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:[indicator(\(singleCheckViewHeight))]-10-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += iconVerticalConstraints

            let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:[indicator(\(singleCheckViewWidth))]-10-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += horizontalConstraints
```

i don't see the image anymore, if i try to put image in a top left with this code:

```
            let iconVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "V:|-10-[indicator(\(singleCheckViewHeight))]",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += iconVerticalConstraints

            let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:[indicator(\(singleCheckViewWidth))]-10-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            allConstraints += horizontalConstraints
```

I obtain image outside the container, like the image below:

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong? and how can i move the icon in a bottom right angle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all of the parent views haven't been aligned properly, nor the siblings, things could go Awry. On top of that,

`cell.textView!.addSubview(omg!)`

`omg`? I assume you meant `img`? Or am I wrong?

Also, on top of this, there's no mention as to what kind of container you're placing this in?

If it's just an NSView or UIView, then xyz.cell isn't the place to put it. If its a TableiewView, a cell could be, but are the constraints all set up. If its iOS, then is the UITableViewCell, the topmost view "of the cell" i.e., did you add a background view as an image view which could be overshadowing it?

Could you elaborate a little as to what the scenario is so we can get  a better picture? (no pun intended)